# How to construct regular grammar (right linear and left linear both) from regular expression?

Tags: finite-automata, formal-grammars

I am interested in some kind of algorithm to achieve this.

Basically  here is the regular expression `aa*(ab+ a)*` and I want to construct a regular grammar for this.

How I can achieve this ?

Following are some correct regular grammar for above expression :-

`S-->aAB
A--> epsilon | aA
B--> epsilon | aB | abB`

`S-->AB
A-->aA/a
B-->aB/abB/epsilon`

How this grammars are created I am clueless.
Is there any algorithm or some construction method ?

I have constructed this NFA

[image: NFA]

and I am getting this grammar

`S-->aA
A-->aA|aB|aC|epsilon
B-->bC
C-->A|epsilon`

What mistake am I doing ?

Comment: What research have you done?  Descriptions of how to convert a regular expression to a NFA are well-documented, as are descriptions of how to convert automata to a grammar.  This should be in any decent textbook.  It's also easy to convert a grammar to a grammar directly.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). It's better to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Read the first few chapters of *Regular Algebra and Finite Machines* by John Conway.